# How do I persist a MySQL timestamp field as a long (epoch) field in java using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a column in a MySQL table like:

```
createdAt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
```

I want it to be stored in a field like:

```
private Long createdAt;
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Best if you use the supported types in `TemporalType` enum. Longs would require a converter.

Here's a converter for longs:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LongConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, Timestamp> {

   @Override
   public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Long attribute) {
      if (attribute == null)
         return null;
      return new Timestamp(attribute);
   }

   @Override
   public Long convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
      if (dbData == null)
         return null;
      return dbData.getTime();

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I make that converter called on my long field? (I don't want it called on every long field - just the ones that map to MySQL timestamps)

Comment: Just drop it anywhere discoverable by the JPA and it will do the job on every persist. Don't worry it's smart enough, it will only convert on sql columns.

Comment: One thing, I'm not sure the null check is required. It may not even try to convert if it's null. Try it yourself.

Comment: Note : This will require JPA 2.1. On a previous post @DonRhummy was using OpenJPA ... which isn't JPA 2.1 last I looked

Comment: @NeilStockton A converter won't work in JPA 2.0? (The version of openjpa - 2.4.2 - passes JPA 2.0 TCK)

Comment: JPA 2.1 adds `@AttributeConverter`, as per the JPA 2.1 spec. OpenJPA is (well) out of date. Maybe they have a vendor provided equivalent ... see their docs

Comment: @NeilStockton Thank you, so what other options would I have?

Comment: Don't use a long. Use the supported temporal types, then follow @RicardoGodoy's answer,

Comment: @DonRhummy as MouseEvent said, or use a JPA provider that supports `AttributeConverter`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` above `createdAt`

Comment: But `Timestamp != Long`?